# OS X reinstallation and Amazon software.

Tags: install

I just purchased a second hand, 2-Week old MacBook Air. I downloaded the **Mac Office** from Amazon. When installing, I'm prompted to enter an **Administrator Password**, which I still don't have, as the guy who sold me the computer has not yet given it to me.

So, can I reinstall the computer without this password? And if so, will I be able to re-download the Office file from **Amazon Software Library**? And, would this reinstallation solve my problem of not having the computer's Administrator Password?

Answer (score 2):

I the first place, there are **[ways](http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/24/reset-mac-os-x-10-7-lion-password/)** of **resetting** the **Administrator's Password**.

Answering your questions, **yes**, you can reinstall the computer without this password. Just follow **[Apple's](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH3878?viewlocale=en_US)** instructions.

And, **yes**, you'll be able to *re-download* the software from Amazon, as stated in its **[Help Page:](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_200205020_times?nodeId=200205020&#times)**

> You can download an unlimited number of times for personal use. To re-download, go to Your Games and Software Library through the "Your Digital Items" link at the top of the screen and click the download button.

And, again, **yes**, making a clean installation will make a new **Administrator** user, with a new password which will be chosen by you.

**Note**: Both of the links regarding OS X reference Lion, as you never stated which version of OS X you are using. These instructions, though, will work for Mountain Lion too.